# How can we send push notification to remote desktop in which a user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I am creating a website with Angularjs and I wish to send push notification to the user who is logged in some where else. I am trying to do that with the Firebase. But, I couldn't get the device token and send the notification. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: it is not possible without device token. you need some device id to which notification has to be pushed. Do you even generate some device id in your angular app.

Comment: @Shubham Gupta I am not aware of the firebase. But the concept is sending notification to a person who is logged in some where else